# Can an Oracle stored procedure return an object useable in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, object

I am working with a PL/SQL developer on a project.  The other developer is writing the stored procedures I need to call.

One of the stored procedures needs to return everything about a product:

> name, price, description, color,
>   weight, manufacturer, etc - ( 15
>   pieces of info in total )

I assumed that the stored procedure would accept one IN parameter, the product-id and return 15 OUT parameters.

Is there a way that the stored procedure can return an object that I can cast to a custom datatype?  Is this a typical technique, or would you normally return multiple OUT parameters?

Comment: I've never been fond of retrieving OUT parameters in Java, much prefer the function/stored proc return a SYS_REFCURSOR & pull out the columns from the resultset object in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference would be that the procedure (or if it is just retrieving the product information, a function) returned a PL/SQL product object that the Java code retrieves either as a java.sql.STRUCT or as a more strongly typed object.

Oracle has sample code for both approaches on its web site.  Here is an example of the [java.sql.STRUCT approach](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/files/advanced/ObjectOracleSample/Readme.html).  And here is the [strongly typed object approach](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/files/advanced/ObjectJavaSample/Readme.html).  The strongly typed example uses JPublisher to create the strongly typed object classes but the [JDBC Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraint.htm#BABFGIAH) walks you through creating your own mappings.

Comment: One more link for working through JDBC: http://www.lorentzcenter.nl/awcourse/oracle/java.920/a96654/oraoot.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hiberante [provides a way](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) to map the result of a sql query or a stored procedure to a java object. It is a complex Object-Relational Mapping solution, but in most cases it's worth the effort.

Answer (score -2):

SQL queries cannot return an object in any way
you should just return the result of a select operator then construct an object yourself with that result